# Why isn't this a counterexample to Chevalley's theorem on constructible sets?

Tags: algebraic-geometry

Let $f(x) = x^2$ be the morphism from $\mathbb{A}^1_{\mathbb{R}}$ to itself. Then the image of $f$ seems to be the set of $x \geq 0.$ Chevalley's theorem says this image should be constructible, but I don't think that $x\geq 0$ is a constructible set.

So, what's wrong? Is $x\geq 0$ a constructible subset of the affine real line? Am I mis-using Chevalley's theorem?

Comment: For real algebraic sets the image of a projection is in general semi-algebraic, an analogue of constructible ( something about Tarski-Seidenberg elimination)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you are talking about the scheme $\Bbb A^1_{\Bbb R} = \operatorname{Spec} \Bbb R[x]$, then you have mis-identified the image. The prime ideal $(x-a)$ for $a\in\Bbb R$, $a<0$, is the preimage of the prime ideal $(x^2-a)$ under the map $x\mapsto x^2$, so it is in the image. More abstractly, the map $f$ is dominant and finite, hence dominant and closed, hence surjective.

If you are talking about the polynomial map $x\mapsto x^2$ on the set $\Bbb R$, then this is not a a scheme and Chevalley's theorem does not apply- instead, you would be in the realm of semi-algebraic geometry, and the image of any semi-algebraic map is again a semi-algebraic set due to the Tarski-Seidenberg theorem.